# Convert Dart Map to AWS json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I am trying to convert this map

```
Map data =  {allPlayers: ["FakeAcccount One","sas","ads"]}
```

but if I do jsonDecode(data);

it is showing

```
{"allPlayers":["FakeAcccount One","sas","ads"]}
```

which is not a valid json .

Please help

Comment: Looks like valid json to me. Do any validators indicate that it's not?

Comment: @msbit this is AWSJSON if i pass `{}` it works but not with the above json

Comment: shouldn't it be jsonEncode and not decode

Comment: I am not familiar with AWSJSON. How are you loading/using the JSON payload, and what errors do you get?